# How to check what apps that prevent hard disk from sleeping in OS X

Tags: macos, hard-drive, sleep, disk-utility, osx-el-capitan

I am using OSX El-Capitan and i thing there is an app that prevent the harddisk from sleeping and keep it spinning.

Some of the answer i have found is to check and repair the harddisk permission. I have do that within terminal since the Disk Utility in ElCapitan is not as useful as the previous version.

So, is there any command in terminal or app tat can detect what apps preventing the harddsik from sleeping?

here is the log from `pmset -g`

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              0
 halfdim              1
 sms                  1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         2
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Comment: Check `pmset -g` Also why is Disk Utility un-useful ?

Comment: hhmm, what should i check there? some keyword maybe?

Comment: disksleep and sleep is set to 10. But it keep spinning.

Comment: Quite frequently its a bluetooth device or the service in the computer. Update your post with output of `pmset -g` and someone will direct you

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like updated

Answer (score 0):

I did some search and notice the standby is set to 0. So i set it 1 which is enabling it again by using

```
sudo pmset -a standby 1
```

Now when i close the lid, and for a couple of second the harddsik is stop spinning.